# $\int x^n \sin x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I attempted solving this using parts and after using it twice I get:

$$(-x^n)\cos x + nx^{n-1}\sin x - n \int \sin x(n-1)x^{n-2} dx$$

can this indefinite integral be solved using typical under division Calculus I-II coursework?

Comment: You will have to do it $n-2$ more times.

Comment: This is the right idea.  Just keep doing it until you see the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $$ I_n = \int x^n\sin(x)dx $$
$$U_n = \int x^n\cos(x)dx$$
Integration by parts 
$$ I_n =-x^n\cos(x)+n\int x^{n-1}\cos(x)dx=-x^n\cos(x)+nU_{n-1}$$
$$U_n=x^n\sin(x)-n\int x^{n-1}\sin(x)dx=x^n\sin(x)-nI_{n-1}$$
with 
$$I_0= -\cos(x)$$
$$U_0=\sin(x)$$
Now substitute until you get to $I_0$ or $U_0$ depending on the parity of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that:
$$ \int f(x)\,e^{-x}\,dx = C-\left(f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)+\ldots\right)e^{-x}\tag{1}$$
and by setting $x=iy$:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int x^n\sin x\,dx &=& \text{Im}\int x^n e^{ix}\,dx = \text{Im}\left(i^{n+1}\int y^n e^{-y}\,dy\right)\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
from which it is easy to recover the final expression.